# winpdb: how Repr works?

Tags: python, debugging, eval, winpdb

I've got a UserDict class with redefined `__repr__` and `__str__` and I'm debugging some code using it with WinPDB:

```
class UserDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "this is repr"
    def __str__(self):
       return "this is str"

variable = UserDict()
variable["abc"] = 1
```

Here is a debugging session of that script. Note 2 commands in console: `eval(variable)` and `eval(variable.__repr__())`, issued, when the execution of the script reached the last line:
[image]

If I say `eval(variable)` in WinPDB console, which should fail in a normal python console, it returns the same as in its "Repr" column.

I wonder, how it fills the contents of that "Repr" column and what it really does, when I say `eval(variable)`?

Comment: What `eval` does is to evaluate a string as Python code. It's the exact opposite of what you claim to be looking for. So… what makes you think `eval` is what you want in the first place?

Comment: @abarnert I've used a wrong word. I don't necessarily want to change how it works. I want to know, what it does.

Comment: Meanwhile, `pdb` does not call `eval` on your object to get its repr; it just calls `repr`. And I'm not sure why you expected defining a `UserDict.__repr__` to affect the representation of some completely unrelated classes that you haven't shown us, but… it won't.

Comment: @abarnert you're right, sorry for bad formulation of my question. Edit done.

Comment: If you actually did what you claim in the edit, `eval(column)` would raise `TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string or code object`. (That's for Python 2.7; the wording is slightly different in 3.x and in very old 2.x, but the basic idea is unchanged.) Please show us an actual [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: @abarnert Edited. You're right. `eval` wasn't done in the real python console, it was issued in WinPDB command line and strangely it works there.

Comment: The Winpdb `eval` command is an entirely separate thing from the Python `eval` function. They do somewhat similar things, hence the name.

Answer (score 2):

What [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) does it to evaluate a string as a Python expression.

You do not want to call `eval` on your objects to get their representation. `pdb`/`WinPDB` does not call `eval` on your objects to get their representation. In fact, `eval` is nearly the *opposite* of `repr`.

If you want to see the results of `foo.__repr__()`, you call [`repr(foo)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#repr)—or just type `foo` at the console. Typing *any* expression at the console causes it to show you `repr(that expression)`.

Of course this means that if you type `eval(foo)` at the console, what you will see is `repr(eval(foo))`. But that has nothing to do with `eval`; it's the same as any other expression.

---

Meanwhile, at the [Winpdb console](http://winpdb.org/docs/the-console/), you're not running Python code, you're running Winpdb code. Winpdb has a command named `eval`, which is similar to the Python function `eval`, but it's not the same thing.

As the documentation says, `eval foo` effectively evaluates `foo` in your live debuggee session. Notice that it a fragment that's parseable as a Python expression, *not* a string holding such a fragment.

So, `eval(variable)` in the Winpdb console is similar to `eval("(variable)")` in the interactive interpreter. Which is nearly identical to just `(variable)` in the interactive interpreter. Which is equivalent to `variable`.

But if you type `variable` (or `(variable)` or `eval("(variable)")`) in your interactive interpreter, it prints out `repr(variable)`, which calls your `__repr__` method. Why isn't that happening in Winpdb?

Because printing out the `repr` of any expression you type at the interactive interpreter is a feature of the interactive interpreter, not of the language. While the Winpdb console *could* do the same thing, it doesn't. (This makes it possible to debug problems with `__repr__` methods, and it avoids running code from the debuggee in the debugger without making it explicit.)

So, what about `eval(variable.__repr__())`. As you can probably guess, that's like evaluating the string `"(variable.__repr__())"` in the debuggee. That `.__repr__()` ends up being part of the expression you evaluate in the debuggee environment, so of course it gets called in the debuggee environment. The result is not a `UserDict` object, as in the previous version, but a string.

---

So, finally, what exactly *does* Winpdb show in its Repr column and as the result of calling `eval`? Well, that isn't really documented explicitly, so you can either figure it out through trial and error, or read the source.

Answer (score 0):

eval() executes python code passed as a string. If you want your dict to return "foo" then use repr(myUserDictVariable).